# Elaboré un programa en Python, pero solamente corre desde la shell, ¿cómo creo un ejecutable?

Tags: pyinstaller

Para que mi programa en Python pueda publicarse como una aplicación completa o ejecutable desde otra computadora o en otra plataforma como una plataforma como servicio ¿qué debo hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack overflow en español, tu pregunta es demasiada amplia y le falta mas detalle, deberías de considerar ir a la sección de cómo hacer una pregunta.

http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta quizás es un poco demasiado genérica ya que no especificas que tipo de aplicación es (solo línea de comandos?, tiene GUI?) pero puedes intentar alguna de estas opciones en función de lo que desees:

- Si la idea is distribuir en un entorno *nix que tenga python instalado simplemente añade `#!/usr/bin/env python` al inicio de tu archivo para que cuando lo ejecutes el sistema sepa que programa usar. Luego solo debes convertir el archivo en un ejecutable con `chmod +x filename.py`
- Usar alguna utilidad o extensión para convertir tu archivo en un ejecutable como por ejemplo www.py2exe.org o www.pyinstaller.org (como bien indican más arriba)

Si lo que pretendes es distribuir una aplicación con interfáz gráfica de usuario multiplataforma te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a algunos de los frameworks que existen para ello. Aquí tienes una lista https://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/gui.html

Ten en cuenta que he dado por hecho que la aplicación está hecha con Python v2.x no Python v3.

Espero que esto sea de ayuda.

Comment: Utilizé pyinstaller para crear el ejecutable, pero al ejecutarlo me despilega un error : no module named tkinter . Estoy usando python 3.5 y me script es  " from tkinter import * " . Porqué me daría ese error ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Compila tu proyecto y las dependencias en un "ejecutable" multiplataforma (Actualmente soporta Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris y AIX.). Trabaja con versiones de Python desde 2.7 y 3.3 - 3.5

La sintaxis para hacerlo es (En windows, por ejemplo)

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py
```

(el flag --icon añade un ícono a tu app)

Si no satisface tus necesidades puedes probar

- Py2Exe
- Py2App (para Mac OS X)
- cx_Freeze

Comment: trataré de hacerlo como me indicas, gracias anticipadas.